# Определение шаблонной конструкции

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, c++17

Если я введу create() то должен возвращать Object соответственно. Но проблема заключается в шаблонной конструкций. Вот небольшой код

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

class xObject;
class xGameObject;

typedef shared_ptr<xObject> Object; //буду использовать ее как смарт указатель.
typedef shared_ptr<xGameObject> GameObject; // естественно для xGameObject

//Собственно этот create для xObject оригинал класс... 
template<typename _xTy, typename _ShareTy = shared_ptr<_xTy>>
_ShareTy create(); 

//Собственно этот create для Object для смарт указателей... 
template<typename _ShareTy>
_ShareTy create(); 


//foo Создаю объект 

void main(void)
{
//С обычным классом
  auto sharedObject = create<xGameObject();
//С смарт типом
  auto sharedObject2 = create<GameObject>();
}
```

Comment: Не понял, что вы пытаетесь сделать вот этим: `typedef xObject shared_ptr<xObject>;`?

Comment: Поправил текст.

Comment: То есть вы хотите перегрузить `create`, чтобы он работал по разному для `shared_ptr<T>` и всех остальных типов?

Comment: Да. Все верно. Нужна помощь с перегрузкой.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот шаблон, который позволяет определить, является ли некоторый тип *специализацией* некоторого шаблона:

```
namespace impl
{
    template <typename A, template <typename...> typename B>
    struct is_specialization_of : std::false_type {};

    template <template <typename...> typename T, typename ...P>
    struct is_specialization_of<T<P...>, T> : std::true_type {};
}

template <typename A, template <typename...> typename B>
inline constexpr bool is_specialization_of = impl::is_specialization_of<A, B>::value;
```

То есть `is_specialization_of<std::shared_ptr<int>, std::shared_ptr> == true`, а какой-нибудь `is_specialization_of<int, std::shared_ptr> == false`.

А теперь или используем этот шаблон в SFINAE:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<is_specialization_of<T, std::shared_ptr>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
T create() {std::cout << "1\n"; return {};}

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!is_specialization_of<T, std::shared_ptr>, std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
T create() {std::cout << "2\n"; return {};}
```

Или берем `if constexpr`:

```
template <typename T>
T create()
{
    if constexpr (is_specialization_of<T, std::shared_ptr>)
        std::cout << "1\n";
    else
        std::cout << "2\n";
    return {};
}
```

Или, если компилятор достаточно свежий, то можно выпендриться и вообще сделать концепт (нужен C++20):

```
template <typename A, template <typename...> typename B>
concept specialization_of = impl::is_specialization_of<A, B>::value;

template <specialization_of<std::shared_ptr> T>
T create() {std::cout << "1\n"; return {};}

template <typename T>
T create() {std::cout << "2\n"; return {};}
```

Answer (score 5):

Этого можно достичь с помощью частичной специализации. Для функция она не разрешается, однако тривиально реализуется через класс, при этом отсутствует необходимость писать дополнительные трейты, использовать SFINAE или концепты:

```
template< typename x_Object >
class creator
{
    public: static x_Object create() { return {}; }
};

template< typename x_Object >
class creator< ::std::shared_ptr< x_Object > >
{
    public: static ::std::shared_ptr< x_Object > create() { return {}; }
};

// функция избавляет тольк от лишнего написания ::create, так можно обойтись и без нее
template< typename x_Object >
x_Object create()
{
    return creator< x_Object >::create();
}
```