# С++: Частичная реализация шаблона для указателей

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Пытаюсь написать класс с шаблонными методами. Как сделать так, чтобы избавиться от явной реализации и дублированного кода?

```
class Attribute final
{
public:

    Attribute();
    Attribute(ViInt32   value, bool rEnable, bool wEnable);
    Attribute(ViInt64   value, bool rEnable, bool wEnable);
    Attribute(ViReal64  value, bool rEnable, bool wEnable);
    Attribute(ViBoolean value, bool rEnable, bool wEnable);

    ~Attribute();

    template<typename T>
    void get(T value) const;

    template<typename T>
    void set(T value);

    bool isReadingEnable();
    bool isWritingEnable();

private:

    template<typename T>
    void Init(T value, bool rEnable, bool wEnable);

    bool readingEnable;
    bool writingEnable;

    std::any attribute;
};

template<>
inline void Attribute::set(ViInt32 value)
{
    attribute = value;
}

template<>
inline void Attribute::set(ViInt64 value)
{
    attribute = value;
}

template<>
inline void Attribute::set(ViReal64 value)
{
    attribute = value;
}

template<>
inline void Attribute::set(ViBoolean value)
{
    attribute = value;
}

template<>
inline void Attribute::get(ViInt32* value) const
{
    *value = std::any_cast<ViInt32>(attribute);
}

template<>
inline void Attribute::get(ViInt64* value) const
{
    *value = std::any_cast<ViInt64>(attribute);
}

template<>
inline inline void Attribute::get(ViReal64* value) const
{
    *value = std::any_cast<ViReal64>(attribute);
}
```

Comment: @user7860670 исправил код в вопросе. Не подскажите, как решить задачку ?

Comment: @user7860670 `if constexpr` появилась только в 17 стандарде (и я не уверен что оно сдесь подойдет). Можно также через `std::enable_if`

Comment: Можно сделать аналогично https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1122451/%d0%9e%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%88%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8/1122475#1122475

Answer (score 1):

Не соображу, в чем проблема?

```
class Attribute final
{
public:

    Attribute();
    template<class T>
    Attribute(T  value, bool rEnable, bool wEnable);

    ~Attribute();

    template<typename T>
    void get(T* value) const;

    template<typename T>
    void set(T value);

    bool isReadingEnable();
    bool isWritingEnable();

private:

    template<typename T>
    void Init(T value, bool rEnable, bool wEnable);

    bool readingEnable;
    bool writingEnable;

    std::any attribute;
};

template<class T>
void Attribute::set(T value)
{
    attribute = value;
}

template<class T>
inline void Attribute::get(T* value) const
{
    *value = std::any_cast<T>(attribute);
}
```

Что тут не так?...

Comment: Я так и пытался сделать, но получал ошибку при компиляции.

Comment: Ну приведите немного более полный код - с примером, когда происходит ошибка при компиляции... Вот, в помощь - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example